# Regex: Separating nn:nn from string

Tags: php, regex

I've been at this for hours and none of the solutions here really helped me. I have a text file formatted as "NN:NN String goes here". The actual file is below. I need to regex the Chapter:Verse from the actual string verse. As you can see, not all are separated by newline. The closest I've gotten is `(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})[^\d]*` but it only really separates the NN:NN.

How can I accomplish separating the string?

```
1:1 The book of the generation of Jesus Christ, the son of David, the son of Abraham.

1:2 Abraham begat Isaac; and Isaac begat Jacob; and Jacob begat Judas and his brethren; 1:3 And Judas begat Phares and Zara of Thamar; and Phares begat Esrom; and Esrom begat Aram; 1:4 And Aram begat Aminadab; and Aminadab begat Naasson; and Naasson begat Salmon; 1:5 And Salmon begat Booz of Rachab; and Booz begat Obed of Ruth; and Obed begat Jesse; 1:6 And Jesse begat David the king; and David the king begat Solomon of her that had been the wife of Urias; 1:7 And Solomon begat Roboam; and Roboam begat Abia; and Abia begat Asa; 1:8 And Asa begat Josaphat; and Josaphat begat Joram; and Joram begat Ozias; 1:9 And Ozias begat Joatham; and Joatham begat Achaz; and Achaz begat Ezekias; 1:10 And Ezekias begat Manasses; and Manasses begat Amon; and Amon begat Josias; 1:11
And Josias begat Jechonias and his brethren, about the time they were carried away to Babylon: 1:12 And after they were brought to Babylon, Jechonias begat Salathiel; and Salathiel begat Zorobabel; 1:13 And Zorobabel begat Abiud; and Abiud begat Eliakim; and Eliakim begat Azor; 1:14 And Azor begat Sadoc; and Sadoc begat Achim; and Achim begat Eliud; 1:15 And Eliud begat Eleazar; and Eleazar begat Matthan; and Matthan begat Jacob; 1:16 And Jacob begat Joseph the husband of Mary, of whom was born Jesus, who is called Christ.

1:17 So all the generations from Abraham to David are fourteen generations; and from David until the carrying away into Babylon are fourteen generations; and from the carrying away into Babylon unto Christ are fourteen generations.

1:18 Now the birth of Jesus Christ was on this wise: When as his mother Mary was espoused to Joseph, before they came together, she was found with child of the Holy Ghost.
```

Comment: What are the exact requirements? Should there be a space and uppercase letter following these NN:NNs? Are you just extracting them or do you want to insert something? See [`\b\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}(?=\s*[A-Z])`](https://regex101.com/r/Sny0LI/1)

Comment: I am extracting them. There should be no space after the NN:NN's

Comment: Show us the end result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. The following should work:

```
preg_match_all("/(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})([^\d]*)/", $str, $output_array);

print_r(array_combine($output_array[1], $output_array[2]));
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e5522443d16558890431519ec6dd03a308ca1e32

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: [`(\d+:\d+)\R?\s*(.+?(?=\s*\d+:\d+|$))`](https://regex101.com/r/iNMaWD/3)

**Details**:

- `\d` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
- `\R` Matches any Unicode newline sequence
- `\s` Matches any whitespace character
- `.+?` matches any character (except for line terminators)
- `$` Asserts position at the end of the string
- `?`  Matches between zero and one times
- `|` Or
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `*` Matches between zero and unlimited times

**PHP code**:

```
$text = "1:1 The book of the generation of Jesus Christ, the son of David, the son of Abraham............";

preg_match_all("/(\d+:\d+)\R?\s*(.+?(?=\s*\d+:\d+|$))/m", $text, $matches);
print_r(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [1:1] => The book of the generation of Jesus Christ, the son of David, the son of Abraham.
    [1:2] => Abraham begat Isaac; and Isaac begat Jacob; and Jacob begat Judas and his brethren;
    [1:3] => And Judas begat Phares and Zara of Thamar; and Phares begat Esrom; and Esrom begat Aram;
    [1:4] => And Aram begat Aminadab; and Aminadab begat Naasson; and Naasson begat Salmon;
    [1:5] => And Salmon begat Booz of Rachab; and Booz begat Obed of Ruth; and Obed begat Jesse;
    [1:6] => And Jesse begat David the king; and David the king begat Solomon of her that had been the wife of Urias;
    [1:7] => And Solomon begat Roboam; and Roboam begat Abia; and Abia begat Asa;
    [1:8] => And Asa begat Josaphat; and Josaphat begat Joram; and Joram begat Ozias;
    [1:9] => And Ozias begat Joatham; and Joatham begat Achaz; and Achaz begat Ezekias;
    [1:10] => And Ezekias begat Manasses; and Manasses begat Amon; and Amon begat Josias;
    [1:11] => And Josias begat Jechonias and his brethren, about the time they were carried away to Babylon:
    [1:12] => And after they were brought to Babylon, Jechonias begat Salathiel; and Salathiel begat Zorobabel;
    [1:13] => And Zorobabel begat Abiud; and Abiud begat Eliakim; and Eliakim begat Azor;
    [1:14] => And Azor begat Sadoc; and Sadoc begat Achim; and Achim begat Eliud;
    [1:15] => And Eliud begat Eleazar; and Eleazar begat Matthan; and Matthan begat Jacob;
    [1:16] => And Jacob begat Joseph the husband of Mary, of whom was born Jesus, who is called Christ.
    [1:17] => So all the generations from Abraham to David are fourteen generations; and from David until the carrying away into Babylon are fourteen generations; and from the carrying away into Babylon unto Christ are fourteen generations.
    [1:18] => Now the birth of Jesus Christ was on this wise: When as his mother Mary was espoused to Joseph, before they came together, she was found with child of the Holy Ghost.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only is this reasonably fast, it also trims all leading/trailing white-space from the text values. *All of your lines of text end with `:`, `;`, or `.` I am leveraging that fact to ramp up the pattern efficiency.

If in your real project, some of the sentences contain newline characters (your sample does not) then add `s` after the 2nd pattern delimiter to make the `.` match newline characters as well.

`~(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})\s+(.*?[:;.](?=\s*(?:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})|$))~` 2193steps

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SJCbXY/1)

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5ce09c579853e12652af8f864908cf0d96e5d64c))

```
$text="1:1 The book of the generation of Jesus Christ, the son of David, the son of Abraham.

1:2 Abraham begat Isaac; and Isaac begat Jacob; and Jacob begat Judas and his brethren; 1:3 And Judas begat Phares and Zara of Thamar; and Phares begat Esrom; and Esrom begat Aram; 1:4 And Aram begat Aminadab; and Aminadab begat Naasson; and Naasson begat Salmon; 1:5 And Salmon begat Booz of Rachab; and Booz begat Obed of Ruth; and Obed begat Jesse; 1:6 And Jesse begat David the king; and David the king begat Solomon of her that had been the wife of Urias; 1:7 And Solomon begat Roboam; and Roboam begat Abia; and Abia begat Asa; 1:8 And Asa begat Josaphat; and Josaphat begat Joram; and Joram begat Ozias; 1:9 And Ozias begat Joatham; and Joatham begat Achaz; and Achaz begat Ezekias; 1:10 And Ezekias begat Manasses; and Manasses begat Amon; and Amon begat Josias; 1:11
And Josias begat Jechonias and his brethren, about the time they were carried away to Babylon: 1:12 And after they were brought to Babylon, Jechonias begat Salathiel; and Salathiel begat Zorobabel; 1:13 And Zorobabel begat Abiud; and Abiud begat Eliakim; and Eliakim begat Azor; 1:14 And Azor begat Sadoc; and Sadoc begat Achim; and Achim begat Eliud; 1:15 And Eliud begat Eleazar; and Eleazar begat Matthan; and Matthan begat Jacob; 1:16 And Jacob begat Joseph the husband of Mary, of whom was born Jesus, who is called Christ.

1:17 So all the generations from Abraham to David are fourteen generations; and from David until the carrying away into Babylon are fourteen generations; and from the carrying away into Babylon unto Christ are fourteen generations.

1:18 Now the birth of Jesus Christ was on this wise: When as his mother Mary was espoused to Joseph, before they came together, she was found with child of the Holy Ghost.";

$pattern='/(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})\s+(.*?[:;.](?=\s*(?:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})|$))/';
var_export(preg_match_all($pattern,$text,$out)?array_combine($out[1],$out[2]):[]);
```

Output:

```
array (
  '1:1' => 'The book of the generation of Jesus Christ, the son of David, the son of Abraham.',
  '1:2' => 'Abraham begat Isaac; and Isaac begat Jacob; and Jacob begat Judas and his brethren;',
  '1:3' => 'And Judas begat Phares and Zara of Thamar; and Phares begat Esrom; and Esrom begat Aram;',
  '1:4' => 'And Aram begat Aminadab; and Aminadab begat Naasson; and Naasson begat Salmon;',
  '1:5' => 'And Salmon begat Booz of Rachab; and Booz begat Obed of Ruth; and Obed begat Jesse;',
  '1:6' => 'And Jesse begat David the king; and David the king begat Solomon of her that had been the wife of Urias;',
  '1:7' => 'And Solomon begat Roboam; and Roboam begat Abia; and Abia begat Asa;',
  '1:8' => 'And Asa begat Josaphat; and Josaphat begat Joram; and Joram begat Ozias;',
  '1:9' => 'And Ozias begat Joatham; and Joatham begat Achaz; and Achaz begat Ezekias;',
  '1:10' => 'And Ezekias begat Manasses; and Manasses begat Amon; and Amon begat Josias;',
  '1:11' => 'And Josias begat Jechonias and his brethren, about the time they were carried away to Babylon:',
  '1:12' => 'And after they were brought to Babylon, Jechonias begat Salathiel; and Salathiel begat Zorobabel;',
  '1:13' => 'And Zorobabel begat Abiud; and Abiud begat Eliakim; and Eliakim begat Azor;',
  '1:14' => 'And Azor begat Sadoc; and Sadoc begat Achim; and Achim begat Eliud;',
  '1:15' => 'And Eliud begat Eleazar; and Eleazar begat Matthan; and Matthan begat Jacob;',
  '1:16' => 'And Jacob begat Joseph the husband of Mary, of whom was born Jesus, who is called Christ.',
  '1:17' => 'So all the generations from Abraham to David are fourteen generations; and from David until the carrying away into Babylon are fourteen generations; and from the carrying away into Babylon unto Christ are fourteen generations.',
  '1:18' => 'Now the birth of Jesus Christ was on this wise: When as his mother Mary was espoused to Joseph, before they came together, she was found with child of the Holy Ghost.',
)
```

Explanation:

```
~                        #Pattern delimiter
(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})        #Capture nn:nn as Group1
\s+                      #Match one or more whitespaces (including newlines)
(                        #Start Capture Group2
  .*?                    #Lazily match zero or more non-newline characters
  [:;.]                  #Match a colon, semi-colon, or dot
  (?=                    #Start "lookahead" (aka: match but don't consume)
    \s*                  #Match zero or more whitespace characters
    (?:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})  #Match nn:nn
    |                    #Or
    $                    #Match the end of the entire string
  )                      #End "lookahead"
)                        #End Capture Group2
~                        #Pattern delimiter
```

Answer (score -1):

Regex Lookbehind will make your task easier

`/(?:\d+:\d+).*?(?=(?:\d+:\d+)|$)/s`

Please see https://regex101.com/r/5UDJOz/1